# Object doesn't support property or method 'jscomp_symbol_iterator0'

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using babel 6.7 to build a single page React.js web app. I've tried to include all the relevant polyfills e.g. babel-polyfill to make it compatible with ES5 browsers. Even still, I get a javascript error every now and again like this

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'jscomp_symbol_iterator0'
```

mostly from users on windows 7 & 8.1 running IE10+.

I'm assuming it's something to do with js Symbol.iterator not being supported. Is there a way I can polyfill this for older browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: are all your version of babel up to date? I'm seeing issues on this but theyre old

Comment: Yes I just updated to all the latest versions of babel and all the latest plugins & polyfills. Could you show me which issues you have found? I had a hard time finding anything on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol.iterator'

Pointed to a specific line related to the ES6 syntax of a `for` loop. I.e., I had this:

```
for(let el of document.getElementsByClassName('especial-els')) { /* ... */ }
```

And all I needed to do to fix it was changing this loop to an "old-style" loop:

```
let especialEls = document.getElementsByClassName('especial-els');
for(let i = specialEls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { /* ... */ }
```

This error only occurred in the Edge browser (not in Chrome and not in Firefox) and particularly only in this `for(let i of iterator)` loop (I have other loops of this kind iterating over arrays and the error does not show up). My guess is that `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "especial" iterator.

Comment: I was just running into this as well with a `for (var a of b)` loop. Changing it to a classic for loop and defining my original var as `a = b[i]` worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following 'require' statements:

```
require('core-js/es6/object');
require('core-js/es6/map');
```